# How to do a select in v 12 c oracle for a json nested field containing backslash

Tags: json, oracle, select

I have a json field in a table as below, i am unable to query the "day" from it :

```
{"FID":54,"header_json":"{\"date\":{\"day\":2,\"month\":6,\"year\":2020},\"amt\":10,\"count\":1}"}
```

SQL tried:

```
select jt.*
from order_json o,
json_table(o.order_json,'$.header_json.date[*]'
columns ("day" varchar2(2) path '$.day')) as jt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy: as you can see header_json is just a string, not usual nested json. So you need to get this quoted string and parse as a json again:

```sql
select *
from 
     (
      select--+ no_merge
         jh.*
      from order_json o,
           json_table(o.order_json,'$.header_json[*]'
                      columns (
                              header_json varchar2(200) path '$')
                      ) as jh
     ) headers,
     json_table(headers.header_json,'$.date[*]'
                columns (
                        "day" varchar2(2) path '$.day')
                ) as j
;
```

Full example with sample data:

```sql
-- sample data:
with order_json(order_json) as (
   select
   '{"FID":54,"header_json":"{\"date\":{\"day\":2,\"month\":6,\"year\":2020},\"amt\":10,\"count\":1}"}'
   from dual
)
-- main query
select *
from 
     (
      select--+ no_merge
         jh.*
      from order_json o,
           json_table(o.order_json,'$.header_json[*]'
                      columns (
                              header_json varchar2(200) path '$')
                      ) as jh
     ) headers,
     json_table(headers.header_json,'$.date[*]'
                columns (
                        "day" varchar2(2) path '$.day')
                ) as j
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)